# How does glDrawArrays know what to draw?

Tags: opengl, graphics, rendering, vertex

I am following some begginer OpenGL tutorials, and am a bit confused about this snippet of code:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferObject); //Bind GL_ARRAY_BUFFER to our handle
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0); //?
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0); //Information about the array, 3 points for each vertex, using the float type, don't normalize, no stepping, and an offset of 0. I don't know what the first parameter does however, and how does this function know which array to deal with (does it always assume we're talking about GL_ARRAY_BUFFER?

glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 1); //Draw the vertices, once again how does this know which vertices to draw? (Does it always use the ones in GL_ARRAY_BUFFER)

glDisableVertexAttribArray(0); //?
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); //Unbind
```

I don't understand how `glDrawArrays` knows which vertices to draw, and what all the stuff to do with `glEnableVertexAttribArray` is. Could someone shed some light on the situation?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The call to `glBindBuffer` tells OpenGL to use `vertexBufferObject` whenever it needs the `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`.

`glEnableVertexAttribArray` means that you want OpenGL to use vertex attribute arrays; without this call the data you supplied will be ignored.

`glVertexAttribPointer`, as you said, tells OpenGL what to do with the supplied array data, since OpenGL doesn't inherently know what format that data will be in.

`glDrawArrays` uses all of the above data to draw points.

Remember that OpenGL is a big state machine.  Most calls to OpenGL functions modify a global state that you can't directly access.  That's why the code ends with `glDisableVertexAttribArray` and `glBindBuffer(..., 0)`: you have to put that global state back when you're done using it.

Comment: Ok, one final thing that puzzels me. How does glDrawArrays know which vertex attribute to use. I am assuming I can have more than one, so I could enable index 1 as so: glEnableVertexAttribArray(1), then give that some attributes using glVertexAttribPointer(), however in my example how does glDrawArrays know to use the attributes at index 0 to interpret the format of the data.

Comment: @handuel: It uses *all* enabled vertex attributes. What each attribute means exactly defined through the programming of the vertex shader.

Comment: @datenwolf Ok, so I set vertex attributes, the shader program then uses those + the data in/(pointed to by?) GL_ARRAY_BUFFER to generate output, which glDrawArrays draws? Hopefully that is correct because in that case I finally understand it.

Comment: @handuel: Actually the vertex shader gets into action after glDrawArrays gets called. glDrawArrays simply passes the data for each active vertex attribute enabled using `glEnableVertexAttribArray` into the drawing queue. In the vertex shader there's a binding for each vertex attribute array, and the shader determines what becomes screen position, what color and so on.

Comment: @datenwolf OK, what data do shaders receive? Just what is in GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, or can they get data from other buffers?

Comment: @handuel: When `glVertexAttribPointer(attrib_index, …)` is called the buffer bound by `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, …)` gets bound to the vertex attribute specified by the *first* parameter of `glVertexAttribPointer`. To bind another buffer to another attribute you do another `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, …); glVertexAttribPointer(…);`. –– The call of `glEnableVertexAttribArray` is not required to make the binding between buffer and attribute. But enabling a vertex attribute array makes the `glDraw…` calls use the enabled attributes.

Comment: @datenwolf So does it mean, that I don't need to bind anything to GL_ARRAY_BUFFER before draw call? Is this code OK?:
> glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
> glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

Comment: @JerryLundegaard: Yes, `glDraw…` functions don't care about the buffer binding. The functions for setting up the vertex attribute buffer association do.

Answer (score 5):

DrawArrays takes data from `ARRAY_BUFFER`.

Data are 'mapped' according to your setup in `glVertexAttribPointer` which tells what is the definition of your vertex.

In your example you have one vertex attrib (glEnableVertexAttribArray) at position `0` (you can normally have 16 vertex attribs, each 4 floats).
Then you tell that each attrib will be obtained by reading 3 GL_FLOATS from the buffer starting from position 0.

Comment: Thanks, that helps me to understand. What does glEnableVertexAttribArray do?

Comment: @handuel updated the answer, see the tutorial from arcsynthesis.org

Comment: @fen
But, if drawArrays takes data from ARRAY_BUFFER, does it mean that I cannot use data from multiple buffers in the shader?
Because your cannot have multiple buffers bounded to ARRAY_BUFFER at the same time. 
BTW posted link doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Complementary to the other answers, here some pointers to OpenGL documentation.  According to Wikipedia [1], development of OpenGL has ceased in 2016 in favor of the successor API "Vulkan" [2,3]. The latest OpenGL specification is 4.6 of 2017, but it has only few additions over 3.2 [1].

The code snippet in the original question does not require the full OpenGL API, but only a subset that is codified as OpenGL ES (originally intended for embedded systems) [4]. For instance, the widely used GUI development platform Qt uses OpenGL ES 3.X [5].

The maintainer of OpenGL is the Khronos consortium [1,6]. The reference of the latest OpenGL release is at [7], but has some inconsistencies (4.6 linked to 4.5 pages). If in doubt, use the 3.2 reference at [8].

A collection of tutorials is at [9].

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulkan
3. https://vulkan.org
4. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_ES
5. see links in function references like https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qopenglfunctions.html#glVertexAttribPointer
6. https://registry.khronos.org
7. https://www.khronos.org/opengl
8. https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/es3
9. http://www.opengl-tutorial.org